# How DatasourceTransactionManager and SQLSessionFactoryBean are related with respect to ibatis- spring transaction management

Tags: spring, ibatis, spring-transactions

How DatasourceTransactionManager and SQLSessionFactoryBean are related with respect to ibatis- spring transaction management. I know SQLSessionFactoryBean provides the SQLSession to be used by the DAO. iBatis uses the spring's DatasourceTransactionManager.

How are these SQLsessionFactoryBean and DatasourceTransactionManager related?? This might be a session-transactionmanager question

Answer (score 0):

The **DatasourceTransactionManager** bean is constructed using the same **javax.sql.DataSource** bean that is used to construct the **SQLSessionFactoryBean**, so Spring can manage transactions in the same manner it does when you use any abstraction built upon the DataSource (i.e. JdbcTemplate).

From [mybatis-spring documentation](https://mybatis.github.io/spring/transactions.html):

> Note that the DataSource specified for the transaction manager must be the same one that is used to create the SqlSessionFactoryBean or transaction management will not work.